# Who is God meant to be?

Tags: oyasumi-punpun

I apologise for the theological sounding question, but I couldn't phrase it any better.

In Oyasumi PunPun, PunPun can see God whenever he chants *'Dear God, dear God, tinkle-tinkle hoy'*

This character always has the same expression and is realistic to a point that it seems it has been copied from a photograph or similar media.

Is God based on the appearance of the mangaka or anyone in particular?

[image]

Comment: Probably some mangaka assistant like Maeda-kun in Kumeta's works.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Japanese Yahoo! Answers](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1022024160), he is Kumatsuto, Asano's—the mangaka—close friend.

A [customer review on Japanese Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.jp/review/R7TMSMN9CUD5K) also mentions Kumatsuto as the god (くまつとさん神様)

He is also mentioned in the manga's credits

[image: Kumatsuto's photo]